# Process Builder Metadata Stuck In Change Set

Tags: apex, process-builder, metadata

A few months ago I created an outbound changeset into our production environment. The sandbox was refreshed, and all the work I did in this particular process builder was erased.

However, I just recently found the change set within the production org. I validated it, but it failed, no biggie. But, is there a way to use the metadata to rebuild the process builder I created? There was so much work involved with it and is actually replacing a complex apex trigger.

I'd hate to redo all that work, but if there is some way to rebuild it from the metadata file, that'd be great! I was able to retrieve 13,138 lines of code.

Comment: Did you try deactivating the existing process in the sandbox or production before deploying the change set? There's been a known issue with change sets not deploying process builders over top of active processes for quite some time. I'd recommend you try deactivating the process and see if it will deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing Process Builder metadata and ending up with a result that actually works is risky and unlikely to succeed.

You might be able to package it in a way that could be deployed by, say, Workbench which uses the Metadata API. What I'd suggest is set up a sandbox where you can attempt to do this. If it throws any errors trying to deploy it, you will have to make whatever configuration changes in the sandbox are needed for the original process to pass validation. Make a note of these changes so you can reverse them later. If you can accomplish that you'll end up with something you can open back up in the Process Builder UI to fix up.

Comment: this worked. I created another developer sandbox and deployed the change set from the one developer sandbox to the newly created sandbox with no problems! I don't have to redo the process builder since it all was in tact after all those months. Thank you

Comment: AWESOME! Glad to hear you saved time and got your work back. Process Builder can be so laborious.